# Include path confusion

Tags: php, include

I'm a bit confused why this path doesn't work:

```
include("../../WEBSITE/GAME/champion.php");
```

The file that it is running in is a cron file that executes every 24hrs it is located in

```
ROOT/WEBSITE2/CRON_FOLDER/cronfile.php
```

I wanted to go back to the http root and then work forward from there but it won't let me?

How do I include this file?

Comment: The directory the file is "running in" isn't always the same as the directory that the file is "stored in". If you want to do `includes` relative to a given file, it's often better to make them `absolute` with `__DIR__`

Comment: @MarkBaker how do I do that? :)

Comment: `include(__DIR__ . "/../../WEBSITE/GAME/champion.php");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to do this given your setup is to define a constant variable describing the root path of your site.

```
<?php

define('SITE_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));

$file_path = SITE_ROOT . '/CRON_FOLDER/cronfile.php';

?>
```

OR document root variable can be used.

```
$root = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);

include $root."/CRON_FOLDER/cronfile.php";
```